# setting displayname data annotation dynamically in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, editortemplates

I have a database table with the following fields

item_key,
item_value,
display_name,
uihint

I want to be able to specify in the database table which displaytemplate to use and also the displayname.

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(p=>pageField.item_value, pageField.uihint) %>
```

The UIHint is working, but I can't work out a way of setting the displayname dynamically, the above code is producing something like

> item_value   TEXTBOX
>
> item_value   TEXTBOX
>
> item_value   TEXTBOX

Where I want the item_values titles to be being pulled from the display_name field.

Is it possible to do this with data annotations? Have been looking at the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx and searching around, but haven't managed to find any examples of what I am after

Comment: Why don't you just place simple label with display name or create template for whole pageField type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your cusotm ModelMetaDataProvider to do that. This link should get you started:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx

Comment: I know this was forever ago, but the link no longer works.